# how to checking value of html input tag in html body tag

Tags: laravel

According to the conditions of my project, I want to use the IF command inside the html body tag, the parameter of the IF condition is the tag being empty. I have to do this because the html code will change based on the condition. How can I write the condition to check the input tag null value.

```
    @if (checking value of office_id))
             <div>update code</div>
    @else
             <div>store code</div>
    @endif
    ...

  <div>
     <input id="office_id" class="myform-control">
  </div>
```

Comment: If you assign the value of input like `<input id="office_id" value="{{$value}}"/>` then you can use `$value` in your if/else, else if the value of input will change based on user interactiion (user add text, button click assigning value to input, etc), then it is better to use javascript

Comment: in fact, you may not need to add `value="{{$value}}"` in your input if value will not change, just add it directly in your if/else

Comment: Undefined variable,Sorry, the if/else is before the input tag, I have corrected the above code..Does this have an effect?

Comment: Undefined variable: `$value` should be from controller to blade, or declared in blade using `@php $value = 'what-value-you-want'; @endphp`. To answer your question, no it does not have an effect

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript or jQuery to listen for changes on the input field, and then show or hide different parts of your HTML based on the input value.

```
<div id="updateCode" style="display: none;">update code</div>
<div id="storeCode" style="display: none;">store code</div>

<div>
    <input id="office_id" class="myform-control">
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#office_id').on('input', function() {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();
        if (inputValue) {
            $('#updateCode').show();
            $('#storeCode').hide();
        } else {
            $('#updateCode').hide();
            $('#storeCode').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: tank's,Can I replace the form tag instead of the DIV tag? I mean, in the blade, I want to call one of the store or update events based on the office_id value.
If office_id has a value, call the update event, but if it does not have a value, call the store event.
Please guide me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Livewire with blade here just use
`wire:model.lazy`

**Read more about this :**
https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties